# Extracting text from PDFs in PHP

Tags: php, pdf

I'm creating a php based web application which allows the user to upload a PDF file. This file will then be read and checked for certain data (text).

The problem is I can't figure out how to even open a PDF file in PHP. There are some PDF libraries mainly for creating PDF's, but they don't seem to be very good at reading them.

An alternative solution would be to use an already available solution in Python or something else (as described in other threads on this site) but I'd really like to stay as much as possible in PHP as I intend to later export the data to mysql, etc.

Any input on how to read a PDF and extract data from it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I personally haven't tried this out, but it looks like this one works: http://www.pdfparser.org/documentation
It's just a matter of downloading and telling your code to include it, just like the documentation shows.

Or you could try the class.pdf2text.php found in http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/31030.html